# Angular 5 invalid Date IE 11

Tags: angular, date, internet-explorer, angular5, invalidation

I am using Angular 5 and i try to convert a string to Date. In Chrome is perfectly working but in Internet Explorer 11 i am getting the error of Invalid Date. I tried multiple ways but i haven't succeed. I have also follow the solution provided here [Solution provided](https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings) The string that i have as input is '2018-04-23 15:21:15 +0300' (value) and i am using the following code:

```
var a = new Date(value);
```

I also tried the following :

```
var a = new Date (new Date(value));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies in the format that you pass the required date to the `Date()` object. IE do not support the date format “yyyy-mm-dd” and therefore fail. Following formats are definitely supported across all browsers and would advise sticking to one of these to avoid errors:

```
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd  
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy"  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"  
var d = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds  
var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
```

So in your case, you can use below code to solve the issue

```
var result = "2018-04-23 15:21:15 +0300'".split(" ");
var date=result[0].trim().split("-");
var time=result[1].trim().split(":");

var mydate = new Date(parseInt(date [2], 10),
                  parseInt(date [1], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(date [0], 10),
                  parseInt(time [0], 10),
                  parseInt(time [1], 10),
                  parseInt(time [2], 10));
```

Comment: So i have to check actually every time if i am getting the date in this format '2018-04-23 15:21:15 +0300' in order to split it. I am saying that because i may get the date as '2018-04-23 15:21:15' or '2018-04-23'.

Comment: for the different format, you can identify them using regex pattern and then apply the appropriate function. But will suggest you keep the date in one standard format. It will make the life easy for integrating existing system with various systems.

Comment: I had the same problems with CharJS, worked in chrome, edge etc, but in IE11 I got Invalid Date